# export * as... syntax giving me an error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

This is the culprit line:

```
export * as Teacher from "./Teacher";
```

and I'm getting an error like this from it:

[image: Errors in VSCode]

How can I fix this? I tried adding `"target": "es6"` to `"compilerOptions"` inside `jsconfig.json`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @DenisTsoi perhaps - but I'm not using TypeScript... does VSCode not differentiate between the two when it comes to IntelliSense checking?

Comment: tbh - I thought you could only `export default` or `export fn` - so think this is invalid es6? - You can `import * as Teacher from "./Teacher"`... not export

Comment: @DenisTsoi you most certainly can! in my particular case, I'm exporting a whole bunch of stuff in `./Teacher`, and I want to make it all available under the `Teacher` namespace further up in the tree. My Babel compiler works fine with it; it's only VSCode that's screaming out in agony.

Comment: I've seen VS code throw me these type of syntax errors and the only fix is to restart VS code.